# Scripting using jQuery's offset()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Issue: I have the label where you must put date, after clicking on label the calendar should appear. I made a jQuery script that will make background darker but after this calendar start not appearing in his place. I'm trying to use a *offset()* but after writing nothing happens:

(part of) Code :

```js
< script > // code with issue
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //Get
    var p = $(".e_darker");
    var offset = p.offset();
    //set    
    $(".calendar_in_place").offset({
      top: offset.top,
      left: offset.left
    });
  }); <
/script>

<
script > // scrolls down page to input label
  $(function() {

    $("#radio_eventi").click(function() {
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#radio_eventi").offset().top
        },
        'slow');
    });
  }); <
/script> <
script > // makes dark background appear/dissapear
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".e_darker").click(function() {
      if ($("#darker").show(150)) {
        $(document).mouseup(function() {
          $("#darker").hide(150);
        });
        $(".e_darker").mouseup(function() {
          $("#darker").hide(150);
        });
      } else {
        $("#darker").show(150);
      }
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

```css
.calendar_in_place {
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
}

.in-front {
  z-index: 6;
}

#darker {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: none;
  transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="darker"> </div>
  <!-- div that makes background darker -->
  <!-- imput label -->
  <section id="eventi_spec" class="nascondi">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="datetimepicker11" class="label_no_middle">Data di avvio dell'evento</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="GG/MM/AAAA" data-mask="99/99/9999" class="form-control in_front e_darker" id="datetimepicker11">
    </div>
</body>
```

Site uses Bootstrap.

Comment: Tip: don't add event handlers inside other event handlers.  In this case, every time you click you add new mouseup/down event handlers which will grind your browser to a halt.

Comment: Is the calendar appearing behind your background panel?  Use css z-index to bring it to the front.

Comment: have you set different css `z-index` ? one for the overlay (5), one for the calendar (??) ?

Comment: @freedomn-m callendar apprear on background, so its good. only issue is that callendar appears in left-top corner, but should appear where im clicking on label

Comment: .e_darker is in <input> classes i make this class specially for this scripts

Comment: offset gives value relative to the window . maybe you want to use position insted...which gives value relative to it's parent

Comment: @MihaiT you mean position()? How should i re-write this script to work?

Comment: @MihaiT Yea, i thought this might cause some problems, but calendar is still not in his place, should be about 1044pixels more lower.

Comment: can you share all code ? that makes the calendar appear? so i can replicate your problem

Comment: unfortunately no, i can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking at your code it seems like the problem is with the styles you set to `.calendar_in_place` . you set the positions with `!important` and so it overwrites the values you set with jquery offset .

you can use CSS() instead and remove the !important

see `.test` div in snippet below

```js
    //Get
    var p = $(".e_darker");
    var offset = p.offset();
    //set    
    $(".test").css({ top: offset.top, left: offset.left })
```

```css
.calendar_in_place {
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
}

.test {
  top: 0 ;
  left: 0 ;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
 position:absolute;
}

#darker {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: none;
  transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="darker"> </div>
<!-- div that makes background darker -->
<!-- imput label -->
<section id="eventi_spec" class="nascondi">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="datetimepicker11" class="label_no_middle">Data di avvio dell'evento</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="GG/MM/AAAA" data-mask="99/99/9999" class="form-control in_front e_darker" id="datetimepicker11">
  </div>
  <div class="test">
  </div>
```

Comment: after deleting these !improtant arguments calendar still appear about 1044 pixels too high, is there any way to overwrite .caledar_in_place top argument? i want to appear where i'm clicking

Comment: use `console.log($(".calendar_in_place").offset())` after you give it the values and tell me what result you get in console. Unfortunately it's pretty heard to figure out what's going on if i cannot replicate your problem

Comment: Object {top: 1045, left: 240.46875}
left :240.46875
top: 1045

Comment: so yes. that means that the offset.top of `.e_darker` is 1045 and offset.left is ` 240.46875` . so the problem must be with `.e_darker` . to verify this use ` console.log(offset) ` where `offset` is the variable you calculate

Comment: if you mean this: console.log($(".e_darker").offset()) it gives me this output: Object {top: 1010, left: 240.484375}

Comment: ok, i tried again with this console output: for .calendar_in_place Object {top: 629, left: 240.484375} and for .e_darker Object {top: 1010, left: 240.484375}

Comment: instead of offset. try using `$(".calendar_in_place").css({ top: offset.top, left: offset.left })` and be sure to remove `!important` from css

Comment: still nothing, i think i will use trick with scrolling down and/or re-build scripts, so I can again look closer to script

Comment: if you inspect the `.calendar_in_place` and look at css values what values are under `element.style` for top and left ? are they the same with the `e.darker` offset ? see fiddle here on how it should work . https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/epsbcec2/

Comment: .calendar_in_place arguments are strikeouted and element.style has top: 628px;  left: 240.484px;

Comment: thats why i used '!important'

Comment: well is that what you want ?  the top:0 and left:0 to be overwritten by the values from the jQuery ?